# How to show and hide inputs based upon radio button selection

Tags: javascript, html

I would like for a "postal code" box to show when the country "Canada" is selected, and a "ZIP code" box to show for when the country "USA" is selected, however I cannot seem to get one box to dissapear and the other to appear.

```js
function yesnoCheck() {
  if (document.getElementById('Canada').checked) {
    document.getElementById('ZIP').style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
```

```html
<body>

  Country
  <br> Canada <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" name="country" id="Canada" checked> USA <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" name="country" id="USA"> Other <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" name="country"
    id="Other">
  <br>

  <br>
  <div id="Postal">
    <label for="PostalCA">Postal Code</label>
    <input type="text" id="Postal" name="Postal" placeholder="Your Postal Code">
    <br>
  </div>

  <div id="ZIP">
    <label for="PostalUSA">ZIP Code</label>
    <input type="number" id="ZIP" name="ZIP" placeholder="Your ZIP code">
    <br>
  </div>

</body>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you ok with using jQuery?

Comment: You also have TWO IDs called ZIP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. Just add a check for USA as well, and it would work.

What this code does is that if the Canada radio button is checked, the display of the postal input is block (visible) and the display of the zip input is none (hidden). It does the same, but opposite if the USA radio button is checked.

The reason I used [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) instead of [`visibility`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) is because if you used `visibility`, the element is still there, it's just hidden. That means that there's this weird white space where the element used to be. However, `display` does the same thing, except it gets rid of that weird space by removing the `<input>` and readding it (instead of disappearing and reappearing).

```js
function yesnoCheck() {
  if (document.getElementById('Canada').checked) {
    document.getElementById('Postal').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('ZIP').style.display = 'none';
  }
  if (document.getElementById('USA').checked) {
    document.getElementById('ZIP').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('Postal').style.display = 'none';
  }
}

yesnoCheck();
```

```html
<body>

  Country
  <br> Canada <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" name="country" id="Canada" checked> USA <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" name="country" id="USA"> Other <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" name="country"
    id="Other">
  <br>

  <br>
  <div id="Postal">
    <label for="PostalCA">Postal Code</label>
    <input type="text" id="PostalInput" name="Postal" placeholder="Your Postal Code">
    <br>
  </div>

  <div id="ZIP">
    <label for="PostalUSA">ZIP Code</label>
    <input type="number" id="ZIPInput" name="ZIP" placeholder="Your ZIP code">
    <br>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: This finally worked. Thank you so much for your explanation and code!

Comment: @TheWade822 Your welcome. I'm always glad to help. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 1):

No JS required for this. It's pretty trivial in CSS:

```css
#Postal,
#ZIP {
  display: none;
}

#Canada:checked~#Postal {
  display: block;
}

#USA:checked~#ZIP {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>

  Country
  <br> Canada <input type="radio" name="country" id="Canada" checked> USA <input type="radio" name="country" id="USA"> Other <input type="radio" name="country" id="Other">
  <br>

  <br>
  <div id="Postal">
    <label for="PostalCA">Postal Code</label>
    <input type="text" id="PostalCA" name="Postal" placeholder="Your Postal Code">
    <br>
  </div>

  <div id="ZIP">
    <label for="PostalUSA">ZIP Code</label>
    <input type="number" id="PostalUSA" name="ZIP" placeholder="Your ZIP code">
    <br>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The tags says `javascript` and `html`, so i suggest you this simple snippet:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">

function yesnoCheck() {
    if (document.getElementById('yesCheck').checked) {
        document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display = 'block';
    }
    else document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display = 'none';

}
</script>
Yes <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" name="yesno" id="yesCheck">
No <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" name="yesno" id="noCheck"><br>
<div id="ifYes" style="display:none">
   This box is Magic, it will show and hide when clicking on radio button!
</div>
```

Comment: There's no need for Fiddles. Just place your code in a snippet (available while editing a question/answer) with the `<>` button.

Answer (score -5):

The problem is that you have to hide the Zip intially because you are starting out with Canada checked but you also have **two IDs called ZIP**. You may want to handle the onclick event when the user selects USA too. I have a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yardpenalty/5yxckt79/1/) for you to check out but its in jQuery. radio buttons can be a bit finicky.

**jQuery solution:** 
**HTML**

```
  Country
  <br> Canada <input type="radio"   name="country" id="Canada" checked="checked"> USA <input type="radio" o  name="country" id="USA"> Other <input type="radio"  name="country"
    id="Other">
  <br>

  <br>
  <div id="Postal">
    <label for="PostalCA">Postal Code</label>
    <input type="text" id="Postal" name="Postal" placeholder="Your Postal Code">
    </div>
      <div id="ZIPCODE">
    <label for="PostalUSA">ZIP Code</label>
    <input type="number" id="ZIP" name="ZIP" placeholder="Your ZIP code">
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#ZIPCODE{display:none;}
```

**jQuery onReady**

```
 $("input[type='radio']").on("click",function(){

  if ($('#Canada').is(":checked")) 
    $('#ZIPCODE').css("display","none");
  else 
    $('#ZIPCODE').css("display","inline");

 });
```

Comment: Its just not a valid answer. You're only showing the code OP already has.

Comment: Like I said. Go find something else to do. He hasnt even came up with the solution yet! I merely working the answer out with the user.

Comment: Sure, I will find something else to do.

Comment: @yardpenalty you're not working out the answer with the OP... You're simply repeating what he said, which has no use on Stack Overflow. On Stack Overflow, we give useful answers that help the OP solve his/her problem. We don't repeat what they said and claim it's an answer.